# Apigee: What does SyncMessageCount mean?

Tags: apigee, quota

I'm setting up a Quota like this:

`<Quota async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Quota-Rate-Limit" type="calendar">
    <Identifier ref="verifyapikey.Verify-Api-Key.client_id"></Identifier>
    <Allow count="2000" countRef="apiproduct.developer.quota.limit"/>
    <StartTime>2014-07-01 12:00:00</StartTime>
    <Interval ref="verifyapikey.Verify-Api-Key.apiproduct.developer.quota.interval">1</Interval>
    <TimeUnit ref="verifyapikey.Verify-Api-Key.apiproduct.developer.quota.timeunit">hour</TimeUnit>
    <Distributed>true</Distributed>
    <Synchronous>false</Synchronous>
    <AsynchronousConfiguration>
        <SyncIntervalInSeconds>20</SyncIntervalInSeconds>
        <SyncMessageCount>5</SyncMessageCount>
    </AsynchronousConfiguration>
</Quota>`

I think I'm happy with most of it, but I can't seem to find any information on what the `SyncMessageCount` value does. All I've been able to find is that I'll get a InvalidSynchronizeMessageCountForAsyncConfiguration error if it's <= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either `<SyncIntervalInSeconds>` or `<SyncMessageCount>` for configuring the asynchronous configuration and not both.  If using `<SyncMessageCount>5</SyncMessageCount>`, it means that the quota counts across all Apigee message processors will be synced every 5 requests.  I typically use the time interval, increasing it above the default of 10s to improve performance.  It also depends on how accurate you want to enforce the quota.